# How to configure an event mysql to run every day from monday to friday?

Tags: mysql, events

I have this code

```
CREATE EVENT daily_production
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-11-08 23:45:00'
DO CALL sp_produccionDiaria();
```

Please help me, I want to run this code every day from monday to friday, thanks.

Comment: Do you want to skip Saturday and Sunday ?

Comment: Yes. I do. Now I want to skip only Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried from [event tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html), Use **delimiters**, also **ON COMPLETION PRESERVE**

```
delimiter |    
CREATE EVENT daily_production 
      ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
      STARTS '2015-11-08 23:45:00'
      ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DO
    BEGIN
      CALL sp_produccionDiaria();
   END |

delimiter ;
```

Or else, Write shell script on that MySQL event and then create a cron job

```
00 23 * * Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri /path/mysql_event.sh
```